# HPA calculation is not matching for cpu and memory utilization

Tags: kubernetes, hpa

Below are my HPA profile, Pods and nodes usages. I want to understand how the CPU is crossing 85%.

How is the CPU utilization is being calculated here? When I have only 46 pods and each one of them not crossing max 10m cpu?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`metrics-server` pulls from the embedded cadvisor in each Kubelet. It polls every 60 seconds by default and the CPU usage is looking a total CPU usage seconds over the last few time periods as a fraction of wall clock elapsed time.